# Cannot alter an object table type in oracle

Tags: oracle, object, types, alter

```
create or replace type try_object as object(
    my_name varchar2(10),
    roll number
);
/

create or replace type try_object_tab as table of try_object;
/

alter type try_object modify attribute (my_name varchar2(5)) cascade;
```

after executing the above line i am getting this error

```
Error starting at line : 27 in command -
alter type try_object modify attribute (my_name varchar2(5)) cascade
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-22324: altered type has compilation errors
ORA-22328: object "TRIJIT"."TRY_OBJECT" has errors.
PLS-00719: only widening of attribute 'MY_NAME' constraints is allowed
ORA-06550: line 0, column 0:
PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
22324. 00000 -  "altered type has compilation errors"
*Cause:    The use of the ALTER TYPE statement caused a compilation error.
*Action:   Correct the error reported and resubmit the statement.
```

I wonder what exactly is the error when i am totally adhering to the oracle docs. Can anyone kindly help me out with this ? Thanks..

Comment: What docs are you adhering to?  The error message appears to be pretty informative-- you can't make `my_name` smaller, you can just make it bigger once you have the object table.  Are you saying that you have found a document somewhere that indicates that this is allowed?  If so, it would be helpful to link to the document and to specify the exact Oracle version that you're using.

Comment: sorry dude...i thought that was just an example...and we could do it the other way round as well....anyways thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try drop and adding attribute?

```
ALTER TYPE try_object DROP ATTRIBUTE my_name;
ALTER TYPE try_object ADD ATTRIBUTE my_name varchar2(5);
```